# Why does os.path.dirname() think file after double slash is a directory?

Tags: python, windows, path, os.path, dirname

Function `dirname` from Python module `os.path` should return directory name, so why it does it return file name when we use doubleslash?

```
path = "/a.php"
dirname(path) # result is /
```

vs

```
path = "//a.php"
dirname(path) # result is //a.php
```

Comment: I don't get this result on Linux. You get this result, presumably on Windows, because `//` *actually means something else* for Windows paths (at least, at the *beginning* of the path). It's not Python's choice.